# Java Service Wrapper & shutdown command

Tags: shutdown, java-service-wrapper

I use JSW to wrap HSQLdb server. HSQL docs say I must connect to server and execute "shutdown" command to terminate server correctly. Is there any way to execute such shutdown command from within wrapper when I use standard service management commands like "net service stop" or button "stop" in service properties?

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish, but assume that you are running the HSQL server as service and you want to connect from your application to it and when your application stops, it should also stop the HSQL server?
If that's so, then please take a look at the following page:

http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=619

cheers,

edit:
registering the code to cleanly shutdown HSQL as shutdown hook should work for you I think. Furthermore you can also do this with the WrapperListener.stop function (following [Integration Method #3](http://wrapper-app2:8280/doc/english/integrate-listener.html))

cheers,

Comment: This is not what i need. It would be too simple if it was. My goal is windows service which responds to windows services console controls. When i push stop button i want wrapper to understand my intention to shutdown HSQLDB server and shut it down via  execution of above mentioned command.